# Calculating BigOh, iteration division

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

Have a HW assignment to calculate BigOh, but the iteration in my loop is giving me issues.

The Loop:

```
public static int fragment4b(int n){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n*n; i++)         
        for(int j = i; j>= 1; j /=2)        
            sum +=j; 
}
```

I understand the outer loop to have O(n*n), but i feel something is wrong with my inner

So I get that the inner loop has O( (ln(i)/ln(2)) + 1 )
This seem right? or I barking up the wrong tree

Answer (score 3):

the inner loop repeats the `sum+= j` statement exactly [image]

and the outer loop is repeating this N^2 of times.

so the total number of operations is the sum of the inner loop from 1 till N^2 as follows:[image]

and that is [image]

**EDIT:** when taking the log, take the floor of it.

Comment: I see where I made the mistake. +1 for the simplified answer

Comment: How do you determine that the inner loop repeats lg(i) + 1 times, I computed lets say, i = 4, and ln(4) + 1 = 2.38629 but in the loop, i = 4, 4/2= 2 , i=2, 2/2=1, i=1, 1/2 < 1, so it runs 3 times for i=4, not 2, and it seems to be off more the higher i gets, or am I again missunderstanding BigO....

Comment: take the floor of the log

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi I'm still not sure how you determined that the loop repeats lg(i) + 1 times what tells us that info?

Comment: in your question you wrote: the inner loop is O( (ln(i)/ln(2)) + 1 ) 
ln(i)/ln(2) = lg(2)
one way to check that is to try the first few values of i, and you will see the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I would compute running time as follows:

```
T = log1 + log2 + log3 + ... + log(n^2)
```

In the formula above, the first term is the running time for the first iteration of the outer loop, the second term for the second iteration, and so on.

It is obvious that:

```
T < log(n^2) + log(n^2) + ... + log(n^2) = 2(n^2)logn = O(n^2logn))
```

So the running time is bounded by `O(n^2logn)`.

Comment: I dont see how you get from `log(n^2) + log(n^2) + ... + log(n^2)` to `2(n^2)logn` to `O(n^2logn))` how does 2(n^2)logn = n^2logn

Comment: @Jeff Well, `2(n^2)logn != n^2logn` but rather `2(n^2)logn = O(n^2logn)`. In general, we just remove the constant term and get the big O. You might want to review the definition of big O :)

Comment: Ok, I'll review it again, the teacher went through it really quickly and I'm getting myself lost because of the use of logs, this has been a great help